# Javascript: Passing dynamic data name attribute in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables, dynamic

I have the code below:

```
image_type =  'photo';
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',              
    url: '?q=myid_save_input_image', 
    data:{
       'template_id': 1,
       'image_id': 2,
       'primary_id': 3,
       image_type : 4,  
    }
}).done(function(o){                                                    
});
```

I noticed when the code is executed. Looking at Network tab in Google Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

I am expecting like this:

```
template_id: 1
image_id: 2
primary_id: 3
photo: 4
```

How will I achieved it? `$image_type` is dynamic, so the fourth attribute name can change every now then.

Comment: what is the problem then ?? just change image_type to photo in you ajax code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the object first, then use [] to set dynamic key using variable.

```
var formData = {
   'template_id': 1,
   'image_id': 2,
   'primary_id': 3 
};
image_type =  'photo';
formData[image_type] = 4;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',              
    url: '?q=myid_save_input_image', 
    data: formData
  }).done(function(o){                                                    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea. What was the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Prepare the data variable  beforehand and pass it to AJAX function.

Make it like this:

```
var image_type = "photo";

var dataToPass = {};
dataToPass['template_id'] = 1;
dataToPass['image_id']=2;
dataToPass['primary_id']= 3;
 dataToPass[image_type] = 4;
```